# Menu as prism regions + themes problem

Tags: wpf, prism

I am using a Menu control as a region. It works fine, however when I add a theme to my application (Added a resource-dictionary to my App.xaml) normal menus have the theme, but the views inside my region (which are menu-items) don't have this theme.

What might be the reason behind it? Anybody has an idea for a work-around?

Alex.

Answer (score 5):

The problem is that the ItemsControl of the region gets styled but its children do not when the region is used inside a MenuItem. I found a workaround by using dynamic menus from various sources:

[WPF Sample Series – Databound HierarchicalDataTemplate Menu Sample](http://karlshifflett.wordpress.com/2008/02/03/wpf-sample-series-databound-hierarchicaldatatemplate-menu-sample/)

[Building a Databound WPF Menu Using a HierarchicalDataTemplate](http://xamlcoder.com/cs/blogs/joe/archive/2008/11/25/building-a-databound-wpf-menu-using-a-hierarchicaldatatemplate.aspx)

I created an IMenuService and MenuItemViewModel in my Infrastructure project, implement the IMenuService in my Shell project, and use IMenuService in my module to add a menu.

```
public interface IMenuService
{
    List<MenuItemViewModel> Menu { get; set; }
    MenuItemViewModel FileMenu { get; set; }
}

public class MenuItemViewModel : NotificationObject
{
    private string _header;
    private bool _isEnabled = true;
    private ICommand _command;
    private Image _icon;
    private string _inputGestureText;
    private ObservableCollection<MenuItemViewModel> _children;

    public MenuItemViewModel()
    {
        Children = new ObservableCollection<MenuItemViewModel>();
    }

    public MenuItemViewModel(bool isSeparator) : this()
    {
        _isSeparator = isSeparator;
    }

    public string Header
    {
        get { return _header; }
        set
        {
            _header = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged("Header");
        }
    }

    public bool IsEnabled
    {
        get { return _isEnabled; }
        set
        {
            _isEnabled = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged("IsEnabled");
        }
    }

    public ICommand Command
    {
        get { return _command; }
        set
        {
            _command = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged("Command");
        }
    }

    public Image Icon
    {
        get { return _icon; }
        set
        {
            _icon = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged("Icon");
        }
    }

    public string InputGestureText
    {
        get { return _inputGestureText; }
        set
        {
            _inputGestureText = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged("InputGestureText");
        }
    }

    public ObservableCollection<MenuItemViewModel> Children
    {
        get { return _children; }
        set { _children = value; }
    }

    private bool _isSeparator;
    public bool IsSeparator
    {
        get { return _isSeparator; }
        set { _isSeparator = value; }
    }
}
```

MenuService in Shell project:

```
[Export(typeof(IMenuService))]
public class MenuService : IMenuService
{
    [ImportingConstructor]
    public MenuService()
    {
        _menu = new List<MenuItemViewModel>();
        _fileMenu = new MenuItemViewModel {Header = "_File"};
        _fileMenu.Children.Add(new MenuItemViewModel { Header = "_New" });
        _fileMenu.Children.Add(new MenuItemViewModel(true)); // Separator

        _menu.Add(_fileMenu);
    }

    private static Image CreateImage(string url)
    {
        var image = new Image
                        {
                            Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri("Resources/" + url, UriKind.Relative)),
                            Height = 16,
                            Width = 16
                        };
        RenderOptions.SetBitmapScalingMode(image, BitmapScalingMode.NearestNeighbor);
        return image;
    }

    private List<MenuItemViewModel> _menu;
    public List<MenuItemViewModel> Menu
    {
        get { return _menu; }
        set { _menu = value; }
    }

    private MenuItemViewModel _fileMenu;
    public MenuItemViewModel FileMenu
    {
        get { return _fileMenu; }
        set { _fileMenu = value; }
    }
}
```

In Shell.xaml

```
<Window.Resources>
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type MenuItem}" x:Key="separatorStyle">
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type MenuItem}">
                    <Separator HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" IsEnabled="False"/>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>

    <Style BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type MenuItem}}" TargetType="{x:Type MenuItem}">
        <Setter Property="Command" Value="{Binding Command}"/>
        <Setter Property="Icon" Value="{Binding Icon}"/>
        <Setter Property="InputGestureText" Value="{Binding InputGestureText}"/>
        <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="{Binding IsEnabled}"/>
    </Style>

    <HierarchicalDataTemplate DataType="{x:Type infrastructure:MenuItemViewModel}" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Children, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}">
        <ContentPresenter Content="{Binding Header}" RecognizesAccessKey="True" />
    </HierarchicalDataTemplate>

    <local:SeparatorStyleSelector x:Key="separatorStyleSelector"/>
```

In the ShellViewModel:

```
[ImportingConstructor]
    public ShellViewModel(IMenuService menuService)
    {
        Menu = menuService.Menu.ToObservableCollection();
    }

    private ObservableCollection<MenuItemViewModel> _menu = new ObservableCollection<MenuItemViewModel>();
    public ObservableCollection<MenuItemViewModel> Menu
    {
        get { return _menu; }
        set
        {
            _menu = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged("MenuItems");
        }
    }
```

Adding a menu from the module:

```
[ModuleExport(typeof(OptionModule))]
public class OptionModule : IModule
{
    [ImportingConstructor]
    public OptionModule(IMenuService menuService)
    {
        menuService.ToolsMenu.Children.Add(new MenuItemViewModel {Header = "Options", Command = OptionCommand});
    }
}
```

Here is the SeparatorStyleSelector from Karl's site above:

```
public override Style SelectStyle(object item, DependencyObject container)
    {
        if (((MenuItemViewModel)item).IsSeparator)
        {
            return (Style) ((FrameworkElement) container).FindResource("separatorStyle");
        }
        return base.SelectStyle(item, container);
    }
enter code here
```

Comment: This is a great example - the above case works fine for regular commands. How I can ever bind a command in the style to a binding path such as {Binding Path=ActiveDocument.CloseCommand} ? Is there a good way/pattern to do this?

Answer (score 1):

It could be a bug in the Prism Menu region adapter. I'd suggest reporting the issue on CodePlex.

Comment: It seems to be a problem not related to prism. If I create a MenuItem from a different XAML file and then add it to a menu, its appearance is wrong. Prism does the same. I do not know how to solve the problem. Isn't there a way to tell the control to "refresh" its style?

Comment: Can you bind the style to the Parent Template?  I can't remember the syntax off the top of my head...

Comment: @Alex If you can reproduce the problem without using Prism then Prism is not really related to the question. Could you revise the question to remove unrelated details, and add a code example?

Answer (score 0):

I would just iterate the children controls and assign the theme to each of them explicitly.

Comment: And how exactly do you "assign the theme"? Themes reside in application-level resource dictionary. You mean explicitly setting the style property to the resource having the default style key?